# Complex models and displaying data

Tags: c++, qt

I'm just beginning to learn C++ and Qt Framework in particular and I already have a problem right there. The question is how do I create and display data which is not just a string but rather an object, which properties I can access and display. E.g I have a list of employees and I want to display a list which looks like this:

```
---------------------
John Smith
Salary: 50,230
---------------------
Max Mustermann
Salary: 67,000
---------------------
```

The goal is that each item in the list is clickable and opens a new window with the details. Also, the important part is that I can be able to style the properties differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt provide us model and view frameworks, it is pretty flexible.
You could save your data by "model", show the data of your "model" by "view"
and determine how to play your data by "delegate"

The codes of c++ is a little bit verbose, so I use qml from the document to express the idea

```
    import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 640; height: 480

    //the new window
    Window{
        id: newWindow
        width: 480; height:240      

        property string name: ""
        property string salaryOne: ""
        property string salaryTwo: ""

        Rectangle{
            anchors.fill: parent

            Text{
                id: theText
                width:width; height: contentHeight
                text: newWindow.name + "\nSalaryOne : " + newWindow.salaryOne + "\nSalaryTwo : " + newWindow.salaryTwo
            }

            Button {
                id: closeWindowButton
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text:"Close"
                width: 98
                tooltip:"Press me, to close this window again"
                onClicked: newWindow.visible = false
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: salaryModel
        ListElement {
            name: "John Smith"
            SalaryOne: 50
            SalaryTwo: 230
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Max Mustermann"
            SalaryOne: 67
            SalaryTwo: 0
        }
    }

    //this is the delegate, determine the way you want to show the data
    Component {
        id: salaryDelegate
        Item {
            width: 180; height: 40
            Column {
                Text { text: name }
                Text { text: "Salary : " + SalaryOne + ", " + SalaryTwo }
            }

            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent

                //set the value of the window and make it visible
                onClicked: {
                    newWindow.name = model.name
                    newWindow.salaryOne = model.SalaryOne
                    newWindow.salaryTwo = model.SalaryTwo
                    newWindow.visible = true                    

                    view.currentIndex = index                          
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: salaryModel
        delegate: salaryDelegate
    }
}
```

You could separate the window or ListView into different qml files, combine the power of c++ ,qml and javascript. Declarative langauge like qml is pretty good on handling UI.

c++ version

```
#include <memory>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QListView>
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);   

    QStandardItemModel model(2, 1);
    model.appendRow(new QStandardItem(QString("John Smith\nSalary: %1, %2\n").arg(50).arg(230)));
    model.appendRow(new QStandardItem(QString("Max Mustermann\nSalary: %1, ").arg(67) + QString("000\n")));

    QSplitter splitter;

    QListView *list = new QListView(&splitter);
    list->setModel(&model);

    splitter.addWidget(list);

    splitter.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Enhance them by your need, c++ version also support delegate.
You could encapsulate the QListView and open a new window when the
user click on the index(you need QItemSelectionModel to detect which
item you selected).Before you can design higly customize UI,you have 
to study a lot of the model and view frameworks of Qt. Since your case
are pretty simple, default QListView and QStandardItemModel is enough.

Supplement : How to detect which index you selected?

```
//the type of model_selected is QItemSelectionModel*
model_selected = list->selectionModel();

connect(model_selected, SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)),
            this, SLOT(selection_changed(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)));


void imageWindow::selection_changed(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)
{
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly show how this could be done without using QML?

Comment: Actually, I've already solved it a bit differently with using QListWidget and adding QListWidgetItems to it in a loop. For styling I used a custom delegate. Is such method ok, because I'm used to doing things the right way from the start?

Comment: And no, this is no homework, I'm just very curious to learn something new.

Comment: Congratulation. As long as it fit your needs, it is a good method(in my humble opinion).